# Unable to find cause of error in my program

Tags: python, python-2.7, pyqt4

I have this problem in which my execution keeps calling out an error, rendering me unable to execute my program at all.
My error message is, ''mainWindow' object has no attribute 'updateMenu'

But I tried to define it in the earlier part, still I am unable to get it to work.

Can someone tell me where I am wrong?

```
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *

class mainWindow(QDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(mainWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        self.updateMenu()

        self.setShowLbl = QLabel('Show Name')
        self.setShowTxt = QLineEdit()
        self.setShowBtn = QPushButton('Set Show')

        gridLayout01 = QGridLayout()
        gridLayout01.addWidget(self.setShowLbl,0,0)
        gridLayout01.addWidget(self.setShowTxt,0,1)
        gridLayout01.addWidget(self.setShowBtn,0,2)

        self.setLayout(gridLayout01)
        self.setWindowTitle("Set Shot")

        self.connect(self.setShowBtn, SIGNAL('clicked()'), self.updateMenu)

        def updateMenu(self):
            print('working')

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
form = mainWindow()
form.show()
app.exec_()
```

Comment: In your code - double check that `def updateMenu(self):` lines up with `def __init__(self, parent=None)` - if your code is as shown, then you're defining `updateMenu` **inside** your `__init__`...

Comment: Pass... have never used Qt - and I imagine it's probably a matter of style/taste - I'd recommend finding some opensource projects that use it, and take guidance from there. Of course, you can also ask a new question explaining what you're trying to do with an [sscce](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 2):

Your error says that there is no `updateMenu()` method on your `mainWindow` object, if your code is *exactly* as shown in your question, @jon-clements is right, you should lineup the `updateMenu()` inside your class:

```
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *

class mainWindow(QDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(mainWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        self.updateMenu()

        self.setShowLbl = QLabel('Show Name')
        self.setShowTxt = QLineEdit()
        self.setShowBtn = QPushButton('Set Show')

        gridLayout01 = QGridLayout()
        gridLayout01.addWidget(self.setShowLbl,0,0)
        gridLayout01.addWidget(self.setShowTxt,0,1)
        gridLayout01.addWidget(self.setShowBtn,0,2)

        self.setLayout(gridLayout01)
        self.setWindowTitle("Set Shot")

        self.setShowBtn.clicked.connect(self.updateMenu)

    def updateMenu(self):
        print('working')

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
form = mainWindow()
form.show()
app.exec_()
```

I don't have pyqt4 anymore, so I can't test your code as is, but it looks good and working to me.

Comment: Also consider using the new style signal/slot mechanism. Specifically, you can replaced your `self.connect(...)` line with `self.setShowBtn.clicked.connect(self.updateMenu)`

Comment: Thanks guys! Turns out it is the alignment issue.
btw, can I ask whats the difference between the self.connect(...) and the self.setShowBtn.clicked.connect(self.updateMenu) method?

Comment: basically it ends up doing the same thing, but the latter is the new better way to do it which specifies more simply and clearly how your event is handled. And if you've got code completion, then you can choose your event simply by completion after `self.setShowBtn.` ;-) And if I'm not wrong (I have to double check) the old form will get deprecated with Qt5… though I did not do Qt interfaces in a while so I can't be 100% sure on that.